# Do ability modifiers get added to each roll when achieving a critical hit?

Tags: dnd-5e, critical-hit

On a critical hit where for example you roll 2 d4 instead of 1. Do you add your ability modifier twice (one for each roll) or just add it once to the total of the two rolls?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### No

From PHB p. 196 (emphasis mine),

> When you score a critical hit, you get to roll **extra dice** for the attack’s damage against the target. Roll all of the attack’s damage dice twice and add them together. Then add any **relevant modifiers as normal**.
>
> For example, if you score a critical hit with a dagger, roll 2d4 ... and then add your relevant ability modifier.

In short, you roll double the number of dice for a crit. However, the static modifiers are only added *once*.

---

This also extends to added damage on attacks. The extra dice from a Rogue's sneak attack, Fighter's maneuver dice, or a Paladin's smite (as well as numerous other features) all get doubled.
The static bonuses from Dex, Str, or feats like Sharpshooter (and the like) are only added once.

Comment: Even Hex and Hunter's mark damage dice get doubled

Answer (score 4):

**no**

Ability modifier is only added once at the end of the die rolls.

Exemple : you have a 4+ modifier in DEX and you crit with a dagger. You would roll the following :

1d4 (*base weapon dice*) + 1d4 (*crit damage*) + 4 (*DEX modifier*)